# How to convert a text file to array object? Java

Tags: java

I am working on a program that takes in a text file and converts it to a team roster. The text file has unknown length, first name, last name, offence score, and defense score. the name and scores are on the same line. Rachael Adams 3.36 1.93. I can not figure out how to convert each line of the text file into an object. I've searched the internet and all of the examples just have one value per a line and converts it into one big array. I've included some extra imports in the code because i know that I will need them further on in the project(find best attackers, best defenders, make teams of 6, print teams). I've modified code from previous projects that took in numbers separated by lines.

```
class VolleyballFile {
     String fileName;
     int count;

     String currentFileName;

     String outputFile="";
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     double attackScore;
     double defenceScore;

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public VolleyballFile() throws FileNotFoundException {            
        System.out.println("Please enter a file name to get the roster from");
        this.fileName = input.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            int result = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            this.count+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of object do you want to create?

Comment: Move the 4 fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `attackScore`, and `defenceScore` to a different class, e.g. named `Player`. Use `split(" ")` on the lines read. With these two hints, you should be able to do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command `String.split();` you can split a string up to an array of strings. So:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    //int result = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    string[] line = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
    firstName = string[0];
    lastName = string[1];
    attackScore = Float.Parse(string[2]);
    defenceScore = Float.Parse(string[3]);

    this.count+=1;
}
```

I'm not sure if you can `Float.Parse()`, don't remember since I haven't used java recently.

Comment: Thank you, i did something similar here, still running into problems but I got the list to print from the txt file, first semester in computer science started with python then half way threw the class switched to java

Comment: I'm doing A Levels mate XD Good luck! You're welcome to discord me if you want help.

Comment: Oh and if this is as close to a solution as you got for the question, it's good practice to mark it as the accepted answer. The green tick under the vote buttons

Comment: sorry I am pretty new to this website, the class I am taking is all online, I've posted questions in my class community board and emailed my professor with no luck yet, basically trying random bits of code until it works haha